# if I know $\int_0^1 f_n (x) \, dx= 0$ is $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f_n \in \{g \in L_2(0,1) : \int_0^1 g(x) \, dx = 0\}$ be a sequence such that $f_n \to f$. I need to show $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0$. What I have:

$$\|f\|_2 \leq \|f-f_n \|_2 + \|f_n \|_2 < \epsilon + M$$ where I have used that $\|f_n\|_2 < \infty$ and the fact that $f_n \to f$. I am struggling to show the result.

Comment: hi thanks for the response, I don't see how it is a direct consequence - I am trying to prove it.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by $\int_0^1$ is continues. I am trying to prove that the set is closed yes.

Comment: The inner product is continuous in the norm topology. $(f_n,1)=0$ implies $(f,1)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, for large enough $n$, $\|f - f_n \|_2 < \epsilon$. Also,$$\left| \int_0^1 f(x)dx \right|= \left| \int_0^1 (f(x) - f_n(x))dx \right| \le \int_0^1 |f(x) - f_n(x)|dx \\ \le \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f(x) - f_n(x)|^2dx} \times \sqrt{\int_0^1 1^2 dx} = \|f - f_n \|_2 < \epsilon$$

Hence $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = 0$.

Comment: how did you get the first equality?

Comment: @aloegrace because $\int_0^1 f_n(x)dx = 0$.

Comment: got it thanks.1

Comment: Why $\|f-f_n\|_{L^2}\to 0$ ? I mean you use DCT or something ?

Comment: @Svetoslav I inferred this from the OP's "$\|f - f_n \|_2 < \epsilon$".

Comment: Aha, but maybe he also doesn't know why he has it

Comment: @Svetoslav it seems that he/she is satisfied with the answer which blatantly assumes this fact. I hope that OP replies to clear things up.

Comment: $\|f - f_n \|_2 \to 0$ by construction of $f_n$ which I said to be a convergent (to $f$) in that set, which implies $\|f - f_n \|_2 < \epsilon$ for large enough $n$

Comment: @aloegrace you didn't mention that it converges to $f$ in that set, but even if it did, then $f$ is in that set, so there's nothing to prove. It was necessary to mention that convergence happened in $L^2$ for the question to make sense.

Comment: if $f_n$ is in that set, then convergence must be in $L_2$ (this part I did assume as the question didn't specify).